# keep the spinner rotate until the page is not loaded Angularjs

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, angularjs

I am trying to redirect to a HTML page. It takes sometime to load the document. I place a spinner icon until the page is not loaded. but it just shows for a while and it disappear.

Is there any way we can make it hold until the whole page dont get loads up?

here is how my code looks like:

```
 <div class="login-form">
            <input type="email" class="text-input--underbar" placeholder="Email" value="">
            <input type="password" class="text-input--underbar" placeholder="Password" value="">
            <br><br>
            <ons-button modifier="large" class="login-button" ng-click="firstpage()">Log In</ons-button>
            <br><br>
            <ons-button modifier="quiet" class="forgot-password">Forgot password?</ons-button>
            <br><br>
            <ons-icon icon="spinner" class="spinner" size="40px" spin="true"  fixed-width="true" ng-show="spinner"></ons-icon>
          </div>
```

And here is JS

```
var module = angular.module('app', ['onsen']);
module.controller('PageController', function($scope) {
ons.ready(function() {

            $scope.spinner = false;
            $scope.firstpage = function(){
                $scope.spinner = true;
                window.location = "firstpage.html";
            }
    });
});
```

Please let me know if there is anyway of doing this.

Comment: Do you mean whole web page or just controller?

Comment: I mean the whole page